# How to retrieve MS Teams online meetings by using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm a kind of newbie in this API and I've faced a problem.
I have a list of Teams event and I need to get attendee reports. I've not problem to retrieve the data from my own calendar. But the main purpose is to get the data for my Group. I've received a list of group events and try to user joinURL to retrieve online meeting id to retrieve reports. But I received the exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a439f75f-86bc-46fc-a389-5e5fc0905c5c",
            "date": "2023-08-01T13:49:05",
            "client-request-id": "a439f75f-86bc-46fc-a389-5e5fc0905c5c"
        }
    }
```

My request: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ag177zGQUFQkdkWFhVceGsepJ7Vm2I2eBFQpJ4V7VhPA1%40thread.tacv2/1688578673611?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%222dc80d8f-00f4-4b19-bd83-90cd30803a51%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22ca1fdafd-2287-40aa-a9f5-c61a02f1239d%22%7d'](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20%27https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ag177zGQUFQkdkWFhVceGsepJ7Vm2I2eBFQpJ4V7VhPA1%40thread.tacv2/1688578673611?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%222dc80d8f-00f4-4b19-bd83-90cd30803a51%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22ca1fdafd-2287-40aa-a9f5-c61a02f1239d%22%7d%27)

My token credentials:
"Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadBasic Channel.ReadBasic.All ChannelMember.Read.All Chat.Read Chat.ReadBasic ChatMember.Read Group.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All OnlineMeetingArtifact.Read.All OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All OnlineMeetings.Read OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All Team.ReadBasic.All User.Read profile openid email"

Additionally I'm not an admin or meeting organizer. I use a delegated account to retrieve the data. Is any thoughts how to break the down this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This error occurs Either the signed-in user does not have sufficient privileges, or you need to consent to one of the permissions on the Modify permissions tab.
Reference Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-retrieve-an-online-meeting-by-meeting-id

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Graph APIs recently and I faced a similar issue. I was using [Get OnlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to fetch Teams Meeting ID using JoinWebUrl. To use this API we need two things(Application access):

1. `OnlineMeetings.Read.All` permission under Application permission.
2. Application access policy to use the application on behalf of a user.([related links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy))

Even Though these items were correctly configured, I was still facing this error. It turns out that calling the same API endpoint multiple times(for testing) might have blocked the endpoint for that App ID. Fetching meeting details via MeetingCode was working fine though. So, I repeated the same steps by creating a new App in Azure and adding the same permissions to it and it worked on the newly created Azure App.

Hope it Helps.